# Fresh installation of Apache on debian

Tags: apache2

I want to remove the apache that is previously installed.

and want to install a fresh copy.How can I do that? I need clear documentation for the installation because after googling i am not getting that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use *aptitude remove* the configuration files will not be removed. To remove these as well do:

```
aptitude purge apache2
```

Then just install again:

```
aptitude install apache2
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: aptitude purge apache2 worked;but apache2 directories are not removed.
does it mean apache is not removed?

Comment: In case there have been some files that have been added manually in a directory, for example under /etc/apache2, then the files and their containing dirs won't be removed as they aren't known to dpkg. 

If you want to remove these files as well you have to do it the manual way:

    rm -r /etc/apache2